# Angularjs Interpolating inside form action attribute in Laravel 5

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

I've learned that adding @ in front of Angular code in Laravel, it works fine. i.e: `<h1>Hello, @{{ yourName }}!</h1>`

My Angularjs ng-repeat is generating different FORMs and A HREFs. Interpolating works for links, but not inside form action attributes.

I want to generate links similar to this one:

```
http://www.example.com/clients/5/edit
```

This works

```
<a class="btn" href="{{ URL::to('clients/') }}/@{{ i.clientid }}/edit">Edit</a>
```

but what I find interesting is that the same href doesn't work inside my form action attributes:

```
<form action="{{ URL::to('clients/') }}/@{{ i.clientid }}/edit" method="POST">
```

I get the following error message:

> "Error: [$interpolate:noconcat] Error while interpolating:
>   http://www.example.com/clients/{{ i.clientid }}/edit Strict Contextual
>   Escaping disallows interpolations that concatenate multiple
>   expressions when a trusted value is required

Using AngularJS 1.4.4

**UPDATE - added code examples**

Angularjs

```
var app = angular.module('instantsearch',[]);

app.controller('instantSearchCtrl',function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('/api/clients').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.items = data.clients;

    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("No data found..");
  });
});


app.filter('searchFor', function(){
    return function(arr, searchString){
        if(!searchString){
            return arr;
        }
        var result = [];
        searchString = searchString.toLowerCase();
        angular.forEach(arr, function(item){
            if(item.first_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
            result.push(item);
        }
        });
        return result;
    };
});
```

HTML (Laravel blade) with two example forms

```
<div ng-app="instantsearch">
    <div ng-controller="instantSearchCtrl">

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="text" class="search" ng-model="searchString" placeholder="Enter your search terms" />
        </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row data-ctrl" ng-repeat="i in items | filter:searchString | limitTo:20 ">
           <div class="col-sm-8">
                @{{ i.first_name }} @{{ i.last_name }} @{{ i.address }}
           </div>

          <div class="col-sm-4">                                     

                <!-- TEST FORM #1 -->                
                 {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'clients/@{{ i.clientid }}' , 'class' => 'pull-right', 'onsubmit' => 'return ConfirmDelete()')) !!}
                 {!! Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE') !!}
                 {!! Form::button('', array('type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-trash')) !!}
                 {!! Form::close() !!}

                <!-- TEST FORM #2 -->                
                <form action="{{ URL::to('clients/') }}/@{{ i.clientid }}" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                    <button>Delete User</button>
                </form>

                 <a class="btn btn-small btn-info pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" href="{{ URL::to('clients/') }}/@{{ i.clientid }}/edit"></a>

                <a class="btn btn-small btn-success pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" href="{{ URL::to('clients/') }}/@{{ i.clientid }}"></a>

          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Generated code before adding angularjs variable

```
<!-- TEST FORM #1 -->                
<form method="POST" action="/public/clients" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="pull-right" onsubmit="return ConfirmDelete()"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="hkjrehkgjehjk">
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></button>
</form>

<!-- TEST FORM #2 -->                                
<form action="/public/clients" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="hkjrehkgjehjk">
    <button>Delete User</button>
</form>

<a class="btn btn-small btn-info pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" href="/public/clients/{{ i.clientid }}/edit"></a>

<a class="btn btn-small btn-success pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" href="/public/clients/{{ i.clientid }}"></a>
```

Generated code after adding angularjs variable to forms - forms not showing and getting "Error: [$interpolate:noconcat] Error while interpolating" error

```
<!-- TEST FORM #1 -->   
<form method="POST" action="/public/clients/{{ i.clientid }}" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="pull-right" onsubmit="return ConfirmDelete()"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="hkjrehkgjehjk">
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></button>
</form>

<!-- TEST FORM #2 -->   
<form action="/public/clients/{{ i.clientid }}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="hkjrehkgjehjk">
    <button>Delete User</button>
</form>

<a class="btn btn-small btn-info pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" href="/public/clients/{{ i.clientid }}/edit"></a>

<a class="btn btn-small btn-success pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" href="/public/clients/{{ i.clientid }}"></a>
```

Comment: As an advice, don't mix angular with your backend. Never ever. Do your angular in a separate project. You will thank me in the future.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Laravel. As the error says, Angular's "Strict Contextual Escaping" does not allow you to use the `{{ }}` tags inside an `action`.

Comment: I just tested it in my project and it works fine. Show us your Angular controller and your blade template.

Comment: @JesusRodriguez I totally understand what you mean, going for the quick fix

Comment: @JosephSilber ohhhh ok, weird that it would work for an A HREF though

Comment: @SacWebDeveloper Just added code above. I tried with the two form definitions above

Comment: @SacWebDeveloper  what version of angular you are using ? as from 1.2 this will not work (see my answer ..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use multiple expressions in action (also for : src, ng-src), [more informations](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#you-can-only-bind-one-expression-to-src-ng-src-or-action-)

Try using ng-init to set the path, and then use it, in, action. Something like this :

```
 <form ng-init=\"myPath = '{{ URL::to("clients/") }}/'+ i.clientid + '/edit' \" action="{{myPath}}">
```

Comment: Thanks! Seem to work although i'm getting the following msg in the console: Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 0-0 [\] in expression [\"myPath]

Comment: @user3489502 : \" escape is for php (update this for blade), remove this for the front end (the angular expresson lexer used by $parse, is finding the \ as starting caracter so it thow error), also, there is another error  {{ URL::to("clients/") }}'/ => should be {{ URL::to("clients/") }}/'.

Comment: Super thanks! This line did it :   `<form ng-init="myPath = '{{ URL::to("clients/") }}/'+ i.clientid " action="@{{myPath}}" method="POST">` . Removed the backslashes for escape, added @ in action to use Angularjs variable in Laravel and added method="POST"